# Pyinstaller: How to include resources from package used by importlib_resources

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-importlib

I have following project structure:

```
package1/
  __init__.py
  some.py
  package2
    __init__.py
    some.py
    static_data/
      __init__.py
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      ...
my_script.py
```

`my_script.py` contains imports from all over the structure. And python code wotks fine except of `importlib_resources` usage.

I access files with `importlib_resources` (Python 3.6) like so:
`importlib_resources.open_text(static_data, 'file1.txt').readlines()`

Building executable with: `pyinstaller my_script.py -F --noconsole --noupx`

In result executable I get following error:

```
File "lib\site-packages\importlib_resources\_py3.py", line 62, in open_text
File "lib\site-packages\importlib_resources\_py3.py", line 52, in open_binary
FileNotFoundError: 'file1.txt' resource not found in 'package1.package2.static_data'
```

What is the correct way to include resources used with `importlib_resources`?

Answer (score 3):

Non-binary files are not added to the generated binary by PyInstaller by default. You can manually add them using the `--add-data` option, as explained [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search).

Assuming your running windows and the resource files that you are accessing are all within the `package1` top-level package, you can try something like this:

```sh
pyinstaller my_script.py -F --noconsole --noupx --add-data "package1;package1"
```

Comment: A couple of notes. (1) This solution seems to add the whole package, including .py files which are not needed because already bundled in the executable; still it works. (2) If not running on Windows, the `;` in the `--add-data` argument must be replaced with `:`

Answer (score 0):

in the script needs data

```
import platform
if platform.sys.version.split()[0]>='3.7':
    import importlib.resources as importlib_resources
else:
    import importlib_resources

settings = json.loads(importlib_resources.read_text('packagename','data.json'))
```

in the setup.py

```
install_requires=[
        'importlib_resources ; python_version<"3.7"'
      ],
```